# Is Any issue in accessing hidden fields using toString()

Tags: java, android, wifi

I am trying to create an app same as SettingsApp. For this i need network same as Wi-Fi Settings like no internet access or incorrect password. These information is hidden in WiFiConfiguration.

**But** I found that these information is readable using `toString()` method.

Is it good to access those using `toString()`?

Comment: How many of the 20,000+ Android device models did you test?

Comment: @CommonsWare only 1 till now. I got your point.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's not a good design decision. Parsing the `toString()` to extract the information that is otherwise not exposed with methods is going against the principle of the [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). In practice this can get fragile as often subsequent software release can change `toString()` format.

Saying that, it could be that sometimes there simply is no other way. For example if you have to work with 3rd party code that you can't modify in any way and still have to make it work. In this case you might want to introduce [anti-corruption layer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/184472/303097) into your design. You might also want to try using [reflection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/package-summary).

Answer (score 2):

In general: not at all.

You make your code completely dependent on that current implementation of that method.

Sure, it *might* work in the real world, even for longer periods of time, but you always risk that any Android update breaks your string parsing. And that comment is correct, too. What if the method output differs for different devices, or more likely, for different types of Wi-Fi connections?!

Therefore calling toString() and parsing its output to acquire information about internal details of an object is considered bad practice, a really terrible hack!